# How do you build a parameter query for Oracle with Visual Web Developer 2010?

Tags: asp.net, oracle, parameters

I am using a dataset and have build my tableAdapter in VWD.  In SQL Server you can use an @somevar to be the parameter.  But what do you put in Oracle to make it look for a parameter so that I can later bind it to a textbox?  I tried ? but it did not work.

Comment: show us what code you have so far

Comment: I can't.  It is using the visual query builder in a dataset object.  There is no code.

Comment: ah. i managed to overlook that you were using the designer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe Oracle PSQL expects parameters of a query to use a colon (":") instead of "@". So, try :somevar.

Comment: Thank you.  I had the hardest time finding that.